# Detached entity when calling method from another service

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a method with `@Transactional` annotation which calls a method from another service and that calls a method from a DAO. I would like manage rollback. The problem is, the method generates an exception:  `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:`.
In this case how can I manage the transaction without an exception. Please help.

Comment: please show us your code of the two services and dao to examine your case better

Comment: the problem that i added transactional annotation in methode A( wich calls methode B from service 2) in service 1 . In service 2 in method B it has repository.findByCode(code) that returns null . when i take off transactional annotation from method A  it works well . but i need the make transactional annotation